# play-pause music by a foot switch in a website

Tags: usb-device

[image]

I want to make a web application that can allow a user to change, play and pause music with foot switch paddle. I can easily do this with a mouse or keyboard but I don't know how to take input from foot switch paddle in a website. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up the foot switch as a USB HID keyboard device. Then you don't have to change anything compared to the keyboard you already know how to interact with.

There would be no difference in electronics between what you want, and a keyboard. The foot switch is just physically different shape than a keyboard key.

Comment: tear apart an old USB keyboard and use the footswitch as one of the keys